# Select newest entry from each column

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table about as follows:

```
id | timestamp | position | size | level
```

- `id` is the primary key and will always have a value
- `timestamp` is a numerical time representation
- `position`, `size` and `level` may have a value, or they may be null

I want to execute a query which will get the newest non-null position, size and level as determined by the timestamp in the row it belongs to.

How do I do that?

Comment: please tag your database,post your attempts and show some sample data.

Comment: ... and the desired result

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for values in *different* rows, then you can do:

```
select (select position
        from t
        where position is not null
        order by timestamp desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as position,
       (select size
        from t
        where size is not null
        order by timestamp desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as size,
       (select level
        from t
        where level is not null
        order by timestamp desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as level;
```

Note:  This is (almost completely) standard SQL.  The exact syntax could vary depending on the database you are using.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM yourTable t
WHERE t.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM yourTable WHERE position IS NOT NULL)
```

If you want to also enforce non `NULL` values for the `size` and `level` columns when finding the max timestamp, you can use the following subquery instead:

```
SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM yourTable WHERE position IS NOT NULL AND
                                           size IS NOT NULL AND
                                           level IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get it to return all collumns without having to specify the name of each with IS NOT NULL

Comment: If you want to check that all three columns are not null, then you need this check.  What do you have in mind?